# Web Resources load time statistics

Tags: performance, web, statistics, analytics, measure

I have searched a lot for some tools that can help me measure how long it takes to load a website's resources. For example, how long does it take to load all CSS files, also all JS files, requests etc.

I'd like to measure these type of resources individually, so after doing site optimizations, I can do a before/after and check whether loadtime has decreased (and on what types of resources had it decreased).

Also, this website requires authentication, so it needs to be a browser plugin, or some kind of internal tool.

EDIT: Firebug, Chrome Developer tools, Google Pagespeed dp not help, because I cannot get the entire load time of all the CSS files, or of all the JS files, unless I calculate them manually :) Each css file, individually.

Any help would be sooo appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: try firebug,pagespeed. check network panel in that which will give you load times for web resources.

Comment: They do not offer a load 'time' for all CSS files, or JS files. It just offers a overall load time (including responses etc)

Answer (score 0):

**maybe this is your Answer**

there are some online website that testing speed of Website and Other... . if you have a good website the first step is testing your code with **[w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/)** and after that solving the problems and test it on **[gtmatrix](http://gtmetrix.com/)**

and other way is downloading **[firebug](http://getfirebug.com)** for firefox on firebug net tab you can see the speed of your code and ...

and read about see searchengineland.com

Answer (score 0):

Do the following step

```
step 1
   View your application in Mozila


step 2
   Right click any where in you app then go 'inspect element with firebug'
   Note-install firebug if not available in your Mozila Firefox Browser.
```

[image]

```
  Step 3
   you will see selection tag on bottom window

step 4
  select 'Net' click on this 'enable' it if not

step 5
 Reload your webpage and see .
```

Comment: Firebug, Chrome Developer tools, Google Pagespeed dp not help, because I cannot get the entire load time of all the CSS files, or of all the JS files, unless I calculate them manually :) Each css file, individually.